# suppress error messages in protractor

Tags: protractor

When running jasmine e2e tests using protractor, I'd like to test if the correct template is rendered, when a non-existing url is being requested by the browser.
But when requesting an invalid url using `protractor.IBrowser.get('valid.tld/invalid')` [1] it would throw an error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Is there a way to suppress just one occurrence of this error message, so my tests wouldn't fail?

[1] When calling `valid.tld/invalid` manually in the browser, the custom 404 template would be rendered (desired behaviour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The call](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.get) browser.get() returns a promise which is either resolved or rejected. In your case you can handle the [rejected promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) of `browser.get()`

```
describe('sample test', function(){
    it('Sample Check', function(){
            browser.get("http://www.jkhaskjhkjashkjasdhkj.com").then(function(){
                // Happy Path Flow
            }).catch(function(err){
                if(err.indexOf('404')>0) {
                    // Flow when the error code - 404 is received
                    console.log(err)
                }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: that'd be exactly what I need, however, it doesn't seem to work: `Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Promise<void>'`

Comment: Its working fine for me .. And I guess you are using typescript and seeing this error .. Can you try without that?